# Is there a maximum allowed of subsamples per sample for encryption of an ISO based media?

Tags: encryption, mp4, specifications, iso, mpeg-4

**ISO/IEC 23001-7
Common encryption in ISO base media file** defines a subsample as:

> **9.5 Subsample encryption**
>
> **9.5.1 Definition (Normative)**
>
> Subsample encryption SHALL divide each sample into one or more contiguous Subsamples. Each Subsample SHALL
>   have an unprotected part followed by a protected part, only one of
>   which MAY be zero bytes in length. (Note: usually both are non-zero
>   values). The total length of all of the Subsamples (BytesOfClearData +
>   BytesOfProtectedData for all Subsamples that make up a sample) SHALL
>   be equal to the size of the sample itself, and they SHALL not overlap.

The specification provides some examples with 8 subsamples per sample.

I can't find any mention of an upper limit for the allowed subsample count.

In a production environment, I encountered streams with up to 10 subsamples per sample.

Is there a limit to the subsample count in specification? It could be in a different document.

Answer (score 1):

I've been researching this and as far as I can tell it's unspecified. However, there is a significantly lower technical limit than szatmary's suggestion.

Unless I'm mistaken, the `saiz` box must encode the length of the sample auxilliary information as a uint8 (`sample_info_size` field). Assuming a zero-length IV field, that gives you (255-2)//6 = 42 subsamples as an upper bound. (or 39, with IV length 16)

Some players ignore the `saiz` box's suggestion and so the limit can be exceeded, but many (most?) do not.

I have limited access to the specification documents so I may be way off base here.

Answer (score 0):

subsample_count is encoded as an unsigned 16 bit integer. Hence the maximum number is 65535.

Comment: I'm looking for a non purely technical limit, if it exists. For example, `IV_size` is defined as an unsigned 8 bit integer but can only have 0, 8 and 16 as valid values.